# SQLite Success Callback Fires Before Transaction Finishes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sqlite, web-sql

In my ASP.NET web form application I need to perform some JQuery operations to gather form data and then iterate through the form data to save to SQLite Database and upon successful completion close the current window.  The Save operation works perfectly if the window remains open, but as soon as I add the window.close to the success call back in my SQLite transaction the window seems to close before the save operation has time to complete.

```
function save(closeWindow)
{
  //Gathering form data and creating the checkListInsert string containing my bulk insert statement  (i.e. Insert Into Table Select .... Union Select...)

  db.transaction(function (tx) {

                tx.executeSql(checkListInsert.substring(0, checkListInsert.length - 6), [], function (tx, result) {
                    if (closeWindow == "Yes") {
                        //window.close();  If left uncommented the data will not save.  When left commented the save occurs but of course the window is still open
                    }
                }, onSQLError);
        });
}
```

Edit:  If I put the window.close() inside of window.setTimeout() for 1 second everything works fine.  So it is definitely a timing issue.  Seems like the callback shouldn't fire until the transaction is complete?!

Comment: We'll need to see the code inside of executeSql.  I would assume that this is where the Ajax is hiding and at first glance it looks like it is not running your close function as a callback correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you're looking for.  The executeSql is there.

Comment: A call to executeSql is in there.  The code inside the function is not.

Comment: All the code is there.  checkListInsert is my SQL insert statement, followed by [] as there are no arguments, followed by my success callback which includes the if statement, followed by my onSQLError callback.

Comment: Yes, the function call and list of arguments are there.  We need to see what happens after that *inside* of executeSql.  Or at the very least I'm getting the feeling that executeSql is part of some sort of 3rd party library.  Is it?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you asking for the actual sql statement? It is a bulk insert statement that I create in a loop as I iterate through form elements.  It creates a string in the format INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT Col1, Col2 UNION SELECT Col1, Col2 UNION SELECT Col1, Col2.  The substring part is to remove the final UNION from the end.  The SQL executes fine and whatever is in my callback happens.  Just not before the insert actually finishes inserting.

Comment: Did some research on executeSql.  Did not realize it is a built in Webkit function I thought it was part of an external javascript library.  That was my confusion.  I haven't used that particular function before so I don't think I'll be much help here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the number of rows in the form as the number of rows expected to be inserted. Compare that
to the `rowsAffected` by the result to verify that the transaction is complete:

```
if (closeWindow == "Yes") 
  {
  if (result.rowsAffected === /*Number of rows inserted*/)
    {
    window.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the transaction to complete, not the executeSql:

```
function save(closeWindow) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(checkListInsert.substring(0, checkListInsert.length - 6), []);
    }, function () { }, function () {
        if (closeWindow == "Yes") {
            window.close();
        }
    });
}
```