# SQLite and JS - determining when transaction is complete

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, transactions

this is my first post but I've searched so much for this solution now and I still can't find the answer. I consider myself a novice JavaScript developer so I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm working on an iPhone game using HTML5. What I want to happen is whenever I die in the game it should update the database with the new score and then jump to a new page (the score screen).

I have a game class (using the word "class" for lack of a better word) that calls the update method and then a callback which *should* call the showScoreScreen function (which closes the current page) once the transaction has completed. The only problem is that it doesn't wait long enough for the transaction to complete and my score is not updated.

If I add some code in there to wait for 1 second before jumping to the score screen then everything works fine. So it's either a case that my callback is being implemented before the transaction has completed OR my callback isn't being implemented correctly (most likely). Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? This is my first time working with SQLite but after hours of going through documentation it seems like I'm doing the right thing.

FYI -

-I tried implementing the callback in the sucess handler instead of the *finally* block but get the same problem.

-The reason I'm passing "self" into *updateScore* is because it changes to a new context inside the *setInterval* function

-I found a similar issue in this thread but no real answer - [SQLite Success Callback Fires Before Transaction Finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568502/sqlite-success-callback-fires-before-transaction-finishes)

```
///////////////////////// GAME CLASS ///////////////////////////////////

endLevel: function(){

    var self = this;            
    self.setGameOver(true);

    // Wait until death animation has played
    var wait = setInterval(function() {
        if(self.canEndLevel){

            var score = self.getScore();
            self.updateScore(self);
            clearInterval(wait);
        }
    }, 200);                               
},

updateScore: function(self){
    //TODO: Get score and determine if higher
    self.dbConnection.updateScore(self.showScoreScreen);    
},

showScoreScreen: function(){

    window.location.href='./score.html?level=' + window.levelNo + '&score=' + 'S'                           
},

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



///////////////////// DBConnection Class //////////////////////////

updateScore: function(callback){            

    var sucessHandler = this.sucessHandler;
    var errorHandler = this.errorHandler;

    try{
        this.db.transaction(
            function (transaction) {        
                transaction.executeSql('update score set grade = "JAME444" where levelId = 1', [], sucessHandler, errorHandler);
            }
        );  
    }
    catch(e){}
    finally {
        callback();
    }
},
.
.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Ok amazing, it works now. I spent some more time debugging and what happens is it hits my upDateScore method but skips the transaction.executeSql and then hits the callback. THEN it hits updateScore again, this time hitting the execute. So I assume the callback was being executed before it even performed the update. Would be interested in knowing why though.

Comment: Then I went back to trying to implement the callback in the sucess handler it it suddenly worked. I think the problem was that when I previously tried this I was not passing in my *self* variable and it was trying to implement the callback under the *window* scope. And finally (I assume, but really just a guess) javascript being javascript then tried to run the function asyncronously anyways. If anyone has any thoughts I'd like to hear them. This was wrecking my head for ages :(

Comment: It could have also been the fact that I previously tried to implement the callback as *updateScore(callback(param))* (doesn't seem to play nice when you specify a call back with parameters this way). Anyways, for the record and for anyone else with similar problems - the sucessHandler way of implementing the callback works.